# Found 1-bit latch for signal and constant value warnings

Tags: vhdl

I've been trying to debug this VHDL code for two days now, but I just don't see where's the error. Here is the code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;


entity SSDDriver is
    Port ( cp : in std_logic;
              iin : in std_logic;
              an : buffer std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
              --7=a, 6=b ...
              segments: out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0));
end SSDDriver;

architecture Behavioral of SSDDriver is
    signal cpo : std_logic;
    --broj BCD znamenki
    constant BCD_NUMBERS : integer := 4;
    --broj bitova ulaznog broja
    constant BITS : integer := 14;
    --broj kodiran BCD-om
    signal BCDNumber : std_logic_vector (BCD_NUMBERS*4-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal BCDForDecoder: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal number: integer range  0 to 9999;
begin
    decoder: entity BCDToSSD port map (bcd => BCDForDecoder, segm => segments (7 downto 1));
    counter: entity djelitelj generic map (COUNTTO => 25000) port map (cpIn => cp, CpOut=> cpo);
    --tocka je uvijek ugasena
    segments(0) <= '1';

    process (iin)
    begin
        if iin='1' then
            number<=3245;
        else
            number<=1111;
        end if;
    end process;

    SwitchDisplay: process (cpo)
    begin
        if rising_edge(cpo) then
            if an="0111" then
                an<="1011";
                BCDForDecoder<=BCDNumber(11 downto 8);
            elsif an="1011" then
                an<="1101";
                BCDForDecoder<=BCDNumber(7 downto 4);
            elsif an="1101" then
                an<="1110";
                BCDForDecoder<=BCDNumber(3 downto 0);
            else
                an<="0111";
                BCDForDecoder<=BCDNumber(15 downto 12);
            end if;
        end if;
    end process SwitchDisplay;

    DoubleDabble: process (number)
        variable num : std_logic_vector (BITS-1 downto 0);
        variable bcd : std_logic_vector (BCD_NUMBERS*4-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
        variable old_number: integer range 0 to 9999;
    begin
        if number/= old_number then
            num := conv_std_logic_vector(number, BITS);

            for i in 0 to BITS-1 loop
                bcd(BCD_NUMBERS*4-1 downto 1) := bcd(BCD_NUMBERS*4-2 downto 0);  
                bcd(0) := num(BITS-1);
                num(BITS-1 downto 1) := num(BITS-2 downto 0);
                num(0) :='0';

                if(i < BITS-1  and bcd(3 downto 0) > "0100") then 
                    bcd(3 downto 0) := bcd(3 downto 0) + "0011";
                end if;

                if(i < BITS-1 and bcd(7 downto 4) > "0100") then 
                    bcd(7 downto 4) := bcd(7 downto 4) + "0011";
                end if;

                if(i < BITS-1 and bcd(11 downto 8) > "0100") then 
                    bcd(11 downto 8) := bcd(11 downto 8) + "0011";
                end if;

                if(i < BITS-1 and bcd(15 downto 12) > "0100") then 
                    bcd(15 downto 12) := bcd(15 downto 12) + "0011";
                end if;
            end loop;
            BCDNumber <= bcd;
        else

        end if;

        old_number := number;
    end process DoubleDabble;
end Behavioral;
```

And here are generated warnings:

> WARNING:Xst:2734 - Property "use_dsp48" is not applicable for this
>   technology. WARNING:Xst:1780 - Signal > is never used or
>   assigned. WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal .
>   WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal .
>   WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal .
>   WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal .
>   WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal .
>   WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal .
>   WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal .
>   WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal .
>   WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal .
>   WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal .
>   WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 16-bit latch for signal .
>   WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal .
>   WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal .
>   WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal .
>   WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal .
>   WARNING:Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal .
>   WARNING:Xst:2734 - Property "use_dsp48" is not applicable for this
>   technology. WARNING:Xst:1426 - The value init of the FF/Latch bcd_0
>   hinder the constant cleaning in the block SSDDriver. WARNING:Xst:1293
>   - FF/Latch   has a constant value of 0 in block . WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch   has a constant value
>   of 0 in block . WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch   has a
>   constant value of 0 in block . WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch 
>    has a constant value of 0 in block .
>   WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch   has a constant value of 0 in
>   block . WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch   has a constant
>   value of 0 in block . WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch  
>   has a constant value of 0 in block . WARNING:Xst:1293 -
>   FF/Latch   has a constant value of 0 in block .
>   WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch   has a constant value of 0 in
>   block . WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch   has a constant
>   value of 0 in block . WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch  
>   has a constant value of 0 in block . WARNING:Xst:1293 -
>   FF/Latch   has a constant value of 0 in block .
>   WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch   has a constant value of 0 in
>   block . WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch   has a
>   constant value of 0 in block . WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch 
>    has a constant value of 0 in block .
>   WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch   has a constant value of 0 in
>   block . WARNING:Xst:1710 - FF/Latch
>
> and so on ...

As result of these warnings, when I implement that module, I get only 0000 displayed on 4 7-segment displays.

This VHDL code should take integer variable (range from 0 to 9999) and display that number using 4 7-segment displays ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to converting to a synchronous design is to make your logic truly asynchronous.

In the DoubleDabble process, just comment the outermost if statement so your BCD conversion logic runs all the time, and see where that gets you.  Your logic has no need for the previous integer value (old_number), and it is the "if number/= old_number" comparison (without using a clock signal and synchronous logic) that is giving the synthesizer fits.

Comment: Ok, I've removed outermost if statement and now I can implement it and it kinda works :) Last digit works correctly (one that represents ones), but other 3 are just rapidly changing. I also get "the following signal(s) form a combinatorial loop" warning which tells me that bcd signal is in combinatorial loop. Any idea why it is and how I can solve that ? thanks :)

Comment: Probably because you never set it to a known value before starting the for loop.  The synthesizer thinks you want to carry-over the results from the previous cycle.

Comment: OMG ! I can't believe this was the problem :) Now that you've told me, it makes sense :) I've put this: "bcd := (others => '0');" before the for loop and it works. Thank you very much !!!!

Answer (score 4):

Is there any reason you have decided to do you entire BCD conversion process asynchronously? This is where all of your latching issues are coming from (Double Dabble Process).

I am almost positive that if you convert that to a synchronous process you should get rid of the "constant cleaning" and "latch" warnings.

The "constant cleaning" warning will trim all your latches to their initial values hence why you see zero all the time.

When you need something to register at an event or instance your should almost ALWAYS use a clock. You might have a nanosecond time difference from when that signal becomes true and when the clock goes high but believe me, having it in time with the clock will save you so many problems in the future.

Comment: Thanks :) Can you tell me what I should do to convert this process to synchronous ? I'm just a beginner, so I'm not sure what should I do.

Comment: Not sure if you still want the synchronous answer. Have you found your solution?

Comment: I got it working asynchronously. But if you can, please tell me how I can do i synchronously. I am doing this only to learn more, so everything is valuable :)